# Use reflection to call method and get a string value back

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a helper manager with following properties:

```
public class ClientDetails
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTelephone { get; set; }
    public string Add1 { get; set; }
    public string Add2 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

I want to 'get' all these properties in one method. Something like:

```
protected string ContactDetails(string propertyName)
{
    var _clientDetails = ManagerHelper.ClientDetails();
    var temp = typeof (ClientDetails);

    var value = temp.GetProperty(propertyName);

    return value.GetValue(_clientDetails); //ERROR
}
```

I have read somewhere that you can use reflection to do these kind of things but I'm not familiar with reflection. I have tried using reflection above however it gives me an error on _clientDetails.

So if I call this method like `string address1 = ContactDetails("Add1")` then it returns me the value in `ClientDetails().Add1`.

Error is "No overload for method 'GetValue takes 1 arguments".

Comment: What is the error? Saying, "It gave me an error" is about as helpful as saying, "It don't worky"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp

Comment: Are you sure `ManagerHealper.ClientDetails()` is giving back a valid `ClientDetails` object? (check the spelling, BTW)

Comment: Yes, it giving me a valid object. Need to changing the spelling:)

Comment: I have looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp   but it's return an object. How do I retrieve the value in the object in run time?

Comment: Just look at the documentation for the method you're trying to call.

Comment: The error is telling you - you can't call `GetValue` with one parameter (until .net 4.5 at least).  [Read the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I have tried return `value.GetValue(_clientDetails , null);`  which returns an object but I don't know how could i get the string I want from it

Comment: @yagzii did you tryed the code in my answer? `return (string)value.GetValue(_clientDetails, null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return (string)value.GetValue(_clientDetails, null);
```

Comment: @DStanley No it is not optionnal see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue(v=vs.100).aspx